# spark streaming reduce by window

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Hi ive a small problem that im not quite understanding..

I have a stream form an eventhub, as part of that stream i maintain state, as part of that state i emit a Map object containing the updates of the state. I now want to group a set of emitted maps together across a window.  so that i only emit a single message for a set of updates emitted but the mapWithState function.

So included .reduceByWindow(reduce, Seconds(15), Seconds(15)) assuming that i could reduce to a single map all emitted values across a 15 second window.  and that i could use a reduce function somewhat as follows;

```
val reduce = (reduced: Map[String, StockStateObject], in: Map[String, StockStateObject]) => {
  val result = mutable.Map[String, StockStateObject]()
  reduced.foreach(kv => result(kv._1) = kv._2)

  in.keys.foreach(key => {
    if (result.contains(key)) {
      //set the value to whichever record has the latest modified date
      if (in(key).lastUpdateDate > result(key).lastUpdateDate)
        result(key) = in(key)
    }
    else
      result(key) = in(key)
  })

  /*if(reduced.getState.size> 0 || pair.getState.size > 0 )
    println("here")
  (reduced + pair).asInstanceOf[StockState]*/

  result.toMap
}
```

which would (hopefully) merge a set of maps together into a single object and ensure that any duplicate key in the reduced object would get updated if the value has been emitted at a later time.  If someone could validate my approach and perhaps correct the reduce function, so that in essese i can reduce anything in that 15 second window and ensure that once a new window appears that im starting from a blank state.. im sure this is the right approach but im missing some subtlety..

Comment: As usual no one is of help here :(